# Android Start Activity for Result

Tags: android

I'm a total newbie to android. I want to send user input from one activity to another, when I enter text and hit the sendText button I return to the main activity but I am  getting 'null' in the textview where the result should be. Have looked at other answers but still no joy!

Main activity, receives user input from other activity

```
TextView textView1;
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


   }
    public void relativeLayout(View view)
   {
   // Create The  Intent and Start The Activity to get The message

      Intent relativeLayoutIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ExplicitRelativeLayout.class);         
    startActivityForResult(relativeLayoutIntent, 2);
   }
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)                
    {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check if the request code is same as what is passed. here it is 2

    if(requestCode==2)
    {
        if(null!=data)
        {
            // fetch the message String
            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String email = data.getStringExtra("email");
            String phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");

            // Set the message string in textView
            textView1.setText("Name: " + name + ""  + "\n" + "Email: " + email + " " + "\n" +"Phone:" + phone );
        }
```

RelativeLayout Activity, user inputs text

```
public class ExplicitRelativeLayout extends AppCompatActivity {


   EditText setName;
   EditText setEmail;
   EditText setPhone;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.explicitrelativelayout);

    // Get the reference of Edit Text
    setName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setName);
    setEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setEmail);
    setPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setPhone);
}


public void sendText (View views)
{
    // get the Entered  message
    String name=setName.getText().toString();
    String email= setEmail.getText().toString();
    String phone=setPhone.getText().toString();
    Intent intentmessage = new Intent();

    // put the message in Intent
    intentmessage.putExtra("Name:",name);
    intentmessage.putExtra("Email:",email);
    intentmessage.putExtra("Phone:",phone);

    // Set The Result in Intent
    setResult(2,intentmessage);

    // finish The activity
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat?

Comment: See my answer to see your isue :)

Comment: You should mark as a correct the answer that given to you the best explanation, not the first one, just saying :P^

Comment: I marked the answer that solved my problem,@Remees M answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a mismatch in your keys your using in two classes

Use `intentmessage.putExtra("name",name);`

Instead of `intentmessage.putExtra("Name:",name);`

Comment: :) enjoyy.. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you create the `keyString` take a look

```
//put the message in Intent
intentmessage.putExtra("Name:",name);
intentmessage.putExtra("Email:",email);
intentmessage.putExtra("Phone:",phone);
```

On this `putExtra` the `keyString` is `Name:`, `Email:` and `Phone:`, and you are trying to get the strings with this `keyString`

```
// fetch the message String
String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
String email = data.getStringExtra("email");
String phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");
```

You are looking for a `name` as a `keyString` but there is nothing on it, cause you decided to call it `Name:`

Take a look on [`putExtra(String name, Bundle value);`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

The string is :

> The name of the extra data, with package prefix.

And the value is :

> The Bundle data value.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Intent class carries all of it is extra data with a HashMap structure which finds items with given id. Your problem is you are putting down different ids for each item in your two different Intent classes, for example:

In relative activity:

```
intentmessage.putExtra("Name:",name);
```

Your id is "Name:"

In your main activity:

```
String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
```

Your id is "name".

Make sure both of the id's you use in your intent classes are the same and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity B:
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//data send to Activity B
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", strtext + "");//your msg
setResult(2, intent);

}


  Activiy A:
  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String sSuName = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

    //txtfavouratecount.setText(sSuName);
```

}

Comment: Thanks to all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code of ExplicitRelativeLayout activity ::

> 1. setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
> 2. keep  same key on both activity.

```
 public void sendText (View views){
            // get the Entered  message
            String name=setName.getText().toString();
            String email= setEmail.getText().toString();
            String phone=setPhone.getText().toString();
            Intent intentmessage = new Intent();

            // put the message in Intent
            intentmessage.putExtra("name:",name);
            intentmessage.putExtra("email:",email);
            intentmessage.putExtra("phone:",phone);

            // Set The Result in Intent
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intentmessage);

            // finish The activity
            finish();
        }
```